# AndEngine Error

Tags: android, andengine

i want to download andengine.jar from googlecode, but i can't find lib folder where andengine exist. Can anybody help me please? Besides that, i have andengine.jar from somewhere. But, there is no packages org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas. Please help me

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the latest versions, you have to get them from GitHub
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

Once you have all the source, since jars are not available you'll need to run this command from within the AndEngine directory to generate the files it requires to build:

```
android -v update project --path e:/dev/andengine/AndEngine
```

*Replace my path with yours, of course*

For more info about the GLES2 version read this forum post: http://www.andengine.org/forums/announces/andengine-gles2-pre-release-on-december-23rd-t6097.html

Answer (score 0):

AndEngine jar is not on the web anymore. The versions you find are old, don't use them.
Instead, install the Mercurial plug-in for Eclipse, then clone the AndEngine project from google code.

Use this tutorial: http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/getting-started-with-andengine-t11.html

Comment: Do not clone what is on Google Code! It contains obsolete version. The source code for AndEngine was moved here: http://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

Answer (score 0):

Check out the AndEngine code from https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine.

Open Eclipse with ADT installed and Android SDK linked. Import your checked out AndEngine code in to your workspace as 'Existing Android Code'.

If your Eclipse is set to auto-build (default setting), it'll build an AndEngine.jar in to the /libs folder for you. You can use this JAR in other projects.

These are the examples you'll have to use with this (latest) version of AndEngine: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples

`org.anddev.andengine` package names are now obsolete.